# Recursive Flight Paths Code VBA Syntax Error

Tags: excel, recursion, syntax-error, flightpath, vba

When I run this code, I get syntax error.
I cannot understand reason. 
I paste all my code. if you need, i can add datas. 
I want to write recurvise code to find all possible flight rote under time constraint. 
find_route function should run again in itself until stop condition satisfied.(flight_time>480)

```
Function find_route(a As Integer, b As Integer) 'a start node, b start time
flight_time = 0
route(0) = a
l = 0
If flight_time <= 480 Then

    If temp_flight_time(a, b) + flight_time <= 480 Then
    l = l + 1
    route(l) = next_destination(a, b)
    flight_time = temp_flight_time(a, b) + flight_time

         find_route(route(l),flight_time)'*******syntax error at this row******

    End If


Else
    Cells(7, 1).Select
    For i = 0 To 30
        ActiveCell.Value = route(i)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Exit Function

End If

End Function

Function temp_flight_time(a As Integer, b As Integer)
temp_flight_time = get_flight_time(a, next_destination(a, b))
End Function
Function get_flight_time(a As Integer, b As Integer) 'a from, b to
Cells(2, 1).Select
Dim ae As Integer
Dim be As Integer
For i = 1 To 50
    ae = ActiveCell.Value   'From
    be = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value  'To
    If a = ae And b = be Then
        get_flight_time = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value 'Flight Time
        Exit For
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Next
End Function
Function next_destination(a As Integer, b As Integer)
Cells(2, 1).Select
Dim ae As Integer
Dim be As Integer
For i = 1 To 50
    ae = ActiveCell.Value  'To
    be = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value  'Departure
    If a = ae And b <= be Then
        next_destination = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Exit For
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line: `Function find_route(a As Integer, b As Integer)`

`find_route` is a function so it returns a value. The return type isn't specified so it returns a Variant.

Problem line: `find_route(route(l),flight_time)`

The function is called but there's nowhere to put the return value. This causes a syntax error because you have to do something with the return value in VBA.

As you never set the return value of the function (which you would do by writing `find_route = ...`), you probably want to make this a 'Sub' instead. Subs don't return anything so that line would now be OK.

Just change the first line to `Sub find_route...` and the corresponding "End Function" to "End Sub"

Comment: i changed function to sub is OK for now. i continue to write algorithm. Thank you.